# iOS5 unable to read symbols for Riven.bundle (file not found)

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios5

Does anyone know what Riven.bundle is and why Xcode is giving me these warnings when debugging on an iPad?

> warning: Unable to read symbols for
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0
>   (9A334)/Symbols/System/Library/TextInput/Riven.bundle/Riven (file not
>   found).
>
> warning: No copy of Riven.bundle/Riven found locally, reading from
>   memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wild guess: Since it's in the "TextInput" directory, and it's probably new in iOS 5, perhaps it's support code for the new split keyboard? The name would be fitting.

Comment: Can you give us more specific answer? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try: Settings > General > Reset All Settings

I was getting this exact issue with the most current builds of both Xcode, the iOS SDK and iOS firmware on my iPad.  Per recommendations on other related threads, I tried deleting the "iOS DeviceSupport" folder and re-collecting symbols, cleaning and rebuilding my app, so on and so on, all to no avail.

What finally fixed this issue for me is restoring my iPad.  Furthermore, I backed up my iPad, then restored it as a new device, then compiled and ran my app which worked perfectly.  Thinking all was well, I restored my old content and settings onto the iPad at which point I started getting the issue again.  From here I went into Settings > General > Reset All Settings which righted the issue again, which leads me to believe this would have fixed the issue from the start, without having to restore the whole device.

Comment: That sounds scary and dangerous.  Have you found any authoritative confirmation for your answer?

Comment: Reset All Settings (and not restoring from backup) also worked for me.