# No copy of Riven.bundle/Riven found locally, reading from memory on remote device

Tags: iphone, xcode

Does anyone have a cooking clue what this means and how to sort it out?

It happens when I debug the app from Xcode on the device.

> warning: Unable to read symbols for
>   /Users//Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0.1
>   (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/TextInput/Riven.bundle/Riven (file not
>   found). warning: No copy of Riven.bundle/Riven found locally, reading
>   from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's harmless, and there's nothing you can (easily) do to fix it -- it's a glitch in the iOS SDK, or iOS itself, or some combination of the two. Don't worry about it.

Also see [this duplicate.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797804/ios5-unable-to-read-symbols-for-riven-bundle-file-not-found)